# Stop titlerule from overlapping with image

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, diagrams, rules

I’m using the “Abey Resume Template” from Overleaf’s Resume Templates.

**How to** ***stop*** **the** `titlerule` **of** `\section` **from** **overlapping with the image**?

Thanks!!

***Picture:***

[image]

***MWE:***

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Abey George
% Based off of: https://github.com/sb2nov/resume
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{-3.0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{-1pt}
\input{glyphtounicode}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}


\definecolor{cvblue}{HTML}{0E5484}
\definecolor{black}{HTML}{130810}
\definecolor{darkcolor}{HTML}{0F4539}
\definecolor{cvgreen}{HTML}{3BD80D}
\definecolor{taggreen}{HTML}{00E278}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\colorlet{name}{black}
\colorlet{tagline}{darkcolor}
\colorlet{heading}{darkcolor}
\colorlet{headingrule}{cvblue}
\colorlet{accent}{darkcolor}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}



%----------FONT OPTIONS----------
% sans-serif
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{noto-sans}
% \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

% serif
% \usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
% \usepackage{charter}


% \pagestyle{fancy}
% \fancyhf{}  % clear all header and footer fields
% \fancyfoot{}
% \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.6in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.19in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.7in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.4in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large\bfseries
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\classesList}[4]{
    \item\small{
        {#1 #2 #3 #4 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{\large#1} & \textbf{\small #2} \\
      \textit{\large#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
      
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}


\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.001\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \small#1 & \textbf{\small #2}\\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}
\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.0in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}


\newcommand\sbullet[1][.5]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$\bullet$}}}}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  RESUME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING----------


\begin{center}
    {\Huge \scshape Your Name} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    city,state \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \small \href{tel:+xxxxxxxxxxxx}{ \raisebox{-0.1\height}\faPhone\ \underline{+xx-9999999999} ~} \href{mailto:yourname@gmail.com}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faEnvelope\  \underline{yourname@gmail.com}} ~ 
    \href{https://linkedin.com/in/yourid}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faLinkedinSquare\ \underline{yourid}}  ~
    \href{https://github.com/yourid}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faGithub\ \underline{yourid}} ~
    \href{https://www.hackerrank.com/yourid}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faHackerrank\ \underline{yourid}} ~
    \href{https://codeforces.com/profile/yourid}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faPoll\ \underline{yourid}}
    \vspace{-8pt}
\end{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \node[xshift=-2.3cm,yshift=-2cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.65cm]{picture.jpeg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

  
\vspace{-30pt}


%-----------EDUCATION-----------
\section{EDUCATION}
\vspace{10pt}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {College Name}{MM YYYY -- MM YYYY}
      {Degree Name - \textbf{CGPA} - \textbf{xx}}{city, country}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
  
%------RELEVANT COURSEWORK-------
\section{COURSEWORK / SKILLS}
    %\resumeSubHeadingListStart
        \begin{multicols}{4}
            \begin{itemize}[itemsep=-2pt, parsep=5pt]
                \item Data Structures \& Algorithms
                \item Operating Systems
                \item Android Development
            \end{itemize}
        \end{multicols}
        \vspace*{2.0\multicolsep}
    %\resumeSubHeadingListEnd
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the location of the figure will be better. Try to change the `yshift=-1.5cm` in:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \node[xshift=-2.3cm,yshift=-1.5cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.65cm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Also, due to you have negative `\vspace{-30pt}` value before the education section, that's why the education section heading so close to the title line. You should avoid using negative value for that.

> Answer the question in your comment:

your rule is defined in here for each section heading:

```
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large\bfseries
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]
```

IF you change above code to:

```
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large\bfseries
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\hrule width\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5cm \vspace{-5pt}]
```

This is make the rule shorter for every section heading like this:

[image]

I think this is not what you wanted. The main reason to cause the rule overlap the figure is because you insert the figure use `tikz` with option `remember picture` and `overlay`. In this way the the figure will take zero space and overlay on the rest contents in your document. But if you don't use those options, like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[xshift=-2.3cm,yshift=-2cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.65cm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You figure will be inserted like this:

[image]

That why I suggest you still use the `remember picture` and `overlay` option, but move the figure a little bit up to not overlap the rule.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! The solution is good and practical, and I’ve upvoted it. Is there a way to make sure the line does not cross the picture, though? I used vspace{-30pt} just to force the line to cross to illustrate my problem.

Comment: @puf I updated the answer to give a explanation.

Comment: got it, thanks so much for the super informative explanation. I’ve accepted the solution.